# Exception in process that owns ContentProvider crashes process that is using ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have two apps. Let's call them DataSource and QueryApp.

DataSource app exports ContentProvider.

```
<provider
    android:name="com.example.ContentProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}"
    android:exported="true"
    android:readPermission="${applicationId}.read" />
```

QueryApp uses ContentProvider from DataSource:

```
context.contentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(uri)?.use { contentProviderClient ->
    contentProviderClient.query(uri, null, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
        ... do something with the cursor ...
    }
}
```

The problem is if the DataSource process crashes during initialization when executing the request, the QueryApp process will crash as well. And I'm unable to catch the exception.

Inside QueryApp process, when calling `acquireContentProviderClient(uri)`, remote exception is received:

```
E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

...

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder:6230_3
Process: com.example.datasource, PID: 6230
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

The exception is attributed to the DataSource process. There is no exception in QueryApp process.
And then both processes crash.

I've tried catching the error but it doesn't work:

```
try {
    context.contentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(uri)?.use { contentProviderClient ->
        contentProviderClient.query(uri, null, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
            ... do something with the cursor ...
        }
    }
} catch (e: Error) {
    /* we won't reach this line */
}
```

I've tried setting UncaughtExceptionHandler but it doesn't work either:

```
// This is the Thread that we are going to make query on
Thread(it, "SafeContentProviderThread").apply {
    setUncaughtExceptionHandler { t, e ->
        Log.e("Uncaught exception caught and swallowed")
    }
}
```

Can I catch the error and prevent QueryApp process from crashing?